# First number of regex should be 0 (validate)

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression like:

`/^([0-9]{2,3})/`

This will accepts 2 or 3 number digits between 0 and 9

`123` or `12`

I need a validate to: if the number has 3 digits, the first should be `0`, in our case `023`

and if not, number should be the 2 digits one: `12`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^0?\d{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ToB80z/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0?` - an optional `0`
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `$` - end of string